# Reload page after change a value of a field [VUE.JS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm totally noob at web development, I've Vue.js project, at `created()` function I'm parsing data and printing it, as I guess is hooking function and called at stage of page rendering or something like that.
I want to call `created()` after a user modifies an input value.

I'm using `v-model` and `watch`:

```
watch: {
  myvalueChanged: function(newVal, oldVal){
     console.log("%s %s", newVal, oldVal);
     // I want call created() again from here
  }
}
```

How can I do this?
P.S. I want to call created() again, not reload page (if its possible)

Comment: why do you need to recall the `create` hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created()` called synchronously after the instance is created. at this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which means the following have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods, watch/event callbacks.

so in your situation i think you need to use methods function. methods can be called whenever you want.

**Example:**

```
watch: {
  myvalueChanged: function(newVal, oldVal){
     this.testMethod(newVal, oldVal);
  }
}

methods: {
  testMethod: function (newVal, oldVal) {
     console.log("%s %s", newVal, oldVal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method and shift all of your on create jobs to newly created method.

Then call this method in created and watch method after change data.

Comment: he doesn't need to reload the page, and if he will do that he redoes the Vue app life cycle

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, sorry, I have misunderstood Melina Golez's question. I have also updated my answer.